# Html form button text size and color

Tags: html, button, text, hyperlink, fonts

I am making a html password protected button that leads to my cp hack

(works, money hack 100 - 5,000 coins work but the hack for 15k is broke so i need to password protect it while i test and fix it)

anyways i want to make the button/text bigger and color it but dont know how

```
<FORM>
<input type="submit" type="button" value="Goto Club Penguin Hack"     
onClick="passWord()"
style="background-color: #bccae;
;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:22%;margin-  
bottom:0%"
border-top: 2px solid #5f6c4d;
border-right: 2px solid #000000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
border-left: 2px solid #5f6c4d;
width: 180px; height: 100px;
font-weight: bold;" />
</FORM>
```

Comment: pay attention to your editor's syntax highlighting. This is not a programming question, it's just a misplaced quote symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The text highlighting in your question's code should tip you off. You have a double-quote (`"`) that is ending the `style` tag prematurely. Try this:

```
<FORM>
<input type="submit" type="button" value="Goto Club Penguin Hack"     
onClick="passWord()"
style="background-color: #bccae;
margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:0%;
border-top: 2px solid #5f6c4d;
border-right: 2px solid #000000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
border-left: 2px solid #5f6c4d;
width: 180px; height: 100px;
font-weight: bold;" />
</FORM>
```